# how to add an icon to a link locally from my computer?

Tags: html, css

I have an icon that that is on my computer locally and I was wondering how I add the icon to a link off my computer without referencing some other website like font awesome or google fonts. The very last link at the bottom of my code in my head tag is the icon that is on my computer locally and I was wondering how I add it to the link that says, "play".

Here's what I want it to look like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViYD4.png)

This is my code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Chess Facts</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/webp" href="C:\Users\nitro\Desktop\Chess Website\images\play logo.swbp"></link>
</head>

<div id="outer-container">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <a href="#"><img src='images/best chess.com logo.png' id="chess-logo" alt="chess_logo" height='33px' width='110px'></a>
        
        <div class="subnav">
            <a href="#" class="subnavbtn">Play</a>
```

Comment: Then what should I do? What is S3 are you talking about CSS3?@tblev

Comment: Does your imgur link not work for using it as an image?  Like this: `<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViYD4.png">`

Comment: I can use the image tag but I don't know how to have it right beside the "play" link.@tblev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps my comments were confusing.  You're asking about styling, my fault.

Like this?

```
  <a href="#" class="subnavbtn"> Play </a>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViYD4.png">
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't that make the link apart of the image? I'm trying to have the image right beside the link. @tblev

Comment: Try reproducing the issue in a `jsfiddle.net`.  Those are very helpful and will increase the rate at which people are willing to help.

Comment: I was wondering how you use css to have the image right next to the link. @tblev

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for the help. @tblev

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking to do is to position the link and the image using flexbox.

[Here is a helpful resource for flexbox!](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

so to start, in HTML, you need to put a  around the elements you want to position, and only those elements because everything in this div will be positioned by flexbox. In this case, the img and the link. Putting the link first is important here as the default flexbox position will put them left to right in order.

```
<div class="flexBox_Container">
   <a href="#" class="subnavbtn"> Play </a>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViYD4.png">
</div>
```

Then, in CSS, you need to do flex positioning on the container/parent of the objects you want to position. You may replace "flexBox_Container" with anything you want. Do "display:flex" to use flexbox positioning. the default positioning is a left to right row. This should put your elements side by side how you want. Justify content will align your elements left, right, or center.

```
.flexBox_Container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

if for some reason the above lines did not work, try adding..

```
    flex-direction: row;
```

if you want the opposite order try

```
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
```

For more details on flexbox see the source I linked above, or [try this flexbox game](https://flexboxfroggy.com/)! Hope this helped!